# How did balance of probabilities come to be called preponderance of the evidence in the US?

Tags: united-states, england-and-wales, legal-terms, legal-history, legal-concepts

The civil standard of proof is rather than "beyond a reasonable doubt" (what criminal standards of proof are called in both England and the US), either the balance of probabilities or a preponderance of the evidence depending if you are in the UK or US. When and how did American lawyers come to call this concept which appears to be semantically identical something different?

Comment: I cannot find any reason for this and it seems like "Two nations seperated by a common language" similar to the difference in names for that sport with the black and white ball (soccer vs. football) or the box that takes you from one floor to another (elevator vs. lift) and the correct pronunciation of the letters "H" and "Z".  Ultimately in the nearly 250 years the two nations have been separated, the languages have drifted.  The terms seem to defining an identical concept and there are elements between U.S. Law and U.K. Law that differ more (such as the Solicitor/Barrister split in U.K.).

Comment: Yes but surely the break must be traceable: did civil claims in the US in 1775 or 1777 or 1791 or 1793 rely on preponderance of the evidence or on balance of probabilities for example? These questions would offer a starting point.

Comment: My first instinct would be to use a Google N-grams study (which I'm not very fluid at doing) to pin down the time frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](https://scholarship.law.ufl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1286&context=flr) may be helpful. The development of a distinct, lower standard of proof for civil cases comes after the US came into existence, thus the expressions were developed independently, after the doctrine itself started to develop. Various expressions are used, often with different implications that could lead to fixing a specific expression to a definite doctrine, for instance "greater weight of the evidence", "more likely than not" as well as the contender expressions.

Earliest expressions of the principle in question include Edward Wynne *Eunomus* (1768)

> Wherever a verdict is given, the Plaintiff at least must give evidence
> to maintain his Declaration: where evidence is produced on both sides,
> the verdict is given for the Plaintiff or Defendant, according to the
> superior weight of evidence.

Richards Wooddeson's 1777 formulation is

> In causes concerning civil rights and property, that side must
> prevail, in favor of which probability preponderates: but the (a)
> humanity of our law never esteems the turn of the balance sufficient
> to convict a man of any, especially a capital, crime. For it requires
> a very strong and irrefragable presumption of guilt to justify the
> infliction of the severer human punishments

In Delaware (1801) in the case [State v. Crocker](https://casetext.com/case/state-v-crocker), 2 Del. Cas. 150, the doctrine is "named", preponderance of evidence:

> In civil cases a preponderance of evidence is sufficient for you to
> convict; in criminal, you should have proof

You can find "balance of probabilities" in a UK case [Head v. Head](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reports_of_Cases_Decided_in_the_High_Cou/8eNNAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22balance%20of%20probabilities%22&pg=PA151&printsec=frontcover) (1823).

The origin of the construction "balance of probabilities" is philosophy and theology, whereas "preponderance of evidence" is a more-distinctly legal expression. Since the underlying ideas were developed separately in the US and England, it is not surprising that different expressions were attached to the doctrine.

Comment: You're a total legend.

Comment: By the way, may I ask what your research process for this answer was like?

Comment: @JosephP. I suppose it started by asking when the doctrine was developed. Ngrams would normally be a useful tool but it is not so good for data from the 18th century and earlier. Often it's a question of lucking into the right law review article.

Comment: What does the (a) mean in "but the (a) humanity of our law never..." Quotation?

Comment: Wooddesson does this a number of times, marking off parts of his exposition with alphabetic division, presumably to express a particular view of conceptual organization, but I don't know what specifically motivates this marking here.

Comment: Head v. Head is perhaps the best case caption I have ever heard. Although [United States v. Approximately 64,695 Pounds of Shark Fins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Approximately_64,695_Pounds_of_Shark_Fins) is still up there.